# Android Studio - Quick keys to add/remove a parent composable?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Flutter, you can quickly add/remove a parent composable by tapping `cmd-return` on a widget. You'll get the drop down list of options. When I do this for Compose, there's no such actions. Is there another way of quickly adding/removing composables?

Comment: check this one for adding a parent
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71947810/6797229