# Flutter style code editing short cuts for jetpack compose?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I´m a little spoiled by these code editing shortcuts Flutter plugins provide (See example screenshot). Does somethings similar exist for Jetpack Compose? I researched a while but couldn´t find anything. Many thanks and happy coding!

[image: Flutter Android Studio plugin code editing shortcut]

Answer (score 5):

There's a shortcut for *Surround with* Ctrl+Alt+J on Windows and ⌥⌘J on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is new, or before I missed it. Turns out you can just use Live Templates:

```
Ctrl + Alt + T
```